# DataGridView AutoSize manipulation

Tags: c#, datagridview, autosize

first I thought the `AutoSize` is a combination of `AutoHeight` + `AutoWidth` put together

then when I got a point where I'd like the grid to take the horizontal space as it wishes but not the vertical I found it's not like that! though it seemed pretty logical to me

anyway, is there a way to get just the width-part from `AutoSize`, like my imaginary `AutoWidth`

note: I've tried out the maximum size & minimum size but no use

the issue is that the last few(+4) rows in the grid are not shown, they are populated into the grid I've checked in debug, and even though that the vertical scroll-bar hits the end
I have to manually re-size the form for them to be shown, but since the rows are populated from a datatable(uncontrollable row count) it won't be solved but enlarging the form

looks like this:

[image: grid hiding rows pic]

the grey row isn't the last seeing the alternating white row with the button and all.. and as I've said I've checked the income query(eg. 21 rows) and the populating function (fills in 21 rows) but the view has only 17 shown

**update**
this is not a *solution*, just a temporary play-over.
I removed the `AutoSize = true` from the grid's initialization and handled `from_Resize` event

```
if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
   this.dgv.AutoSize = true;
else this.dgv.AutoSize = false;
```

it's a half-half way out seems to be working just fine for the time being

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the columns within the datagridview and not the control itself, 
then you would want to set AutoSizeColumnsMode to fill

Comment: nope, I've set the columns and rows size. I mean the grid itself, I'll explain my problem more in the update. thanks for the tip